# Is calling Calendar.getInstance() several times efficient?

Tags: android, performance, instance, android-calendar

I need to get the current time several times in an Android App.

I was wondering if calling `Calendar.getInstance()` was the best implementation, or instead, I could update the given instance (somehow) and make it faster and less expensive (computationally).

Is there any way to update the `Calendar` instance? Is it faster?

Thank you.

Comment: `Calendar.getInstance()` returns an object initialised with the current time and date. If you want you could keep using that instance and set the time and date on that instance when necessary.

Comment: Do you really need the `Calendar` instance? How about using `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead?

Comment: @NielsMasdorp Thing is, how do I update the `Calendar` instance without calling `Calendar.getInstance()`

Comment: @YaroslavMytkalyk You solved it. I will update the instance with `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Feel free to post an answer and I will accept it. I feel so stupid right now haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need just current time, you can get it as `System.currentTimeMillis()`. If you need the `Calendar` features, no need to call `Calendar.getInstance()` every time. Instead, you may use existing `Calendar` reference, and update it by setting the current time, like

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using either of the below instead of creating lots of new Calendar instances.

```
System.currentTimeMillis()

System.nanoTime()
```

If you need a human readable version of the current time, you can **then** use a Calendar instance to convert from the currentTimeMillis (Long) result, such as below

```
Long l = 1491812989036L;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(l);

System.out.println("year: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println("month: " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("day: " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```